# Convert rows into array

Tags: python, arrays, database, postgresql, csv

I want to convert all the rows into array.
E.g. I have multiple values which is stored in CSV.
Suppose in A1 position value is Message
In B1 position value is Field=1234
In C1 position value is Field=0023

Like from A1 to around AZ1 I have data in rows.

So I want to convert it into array after that stored in postgres by different data fields.

**In my csv there is no any column name.**

I'm expecting the python code for this.
After that I want to catch only particular data fields value to created column names.

---

This is my data which is stored like this in csv. So, I want to segregate this data in **database**.

My CSV Data:-  [My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n49H2.jpg)

I want to segregate like this in database from csv file:-  [Segregate like this in & store in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV1E1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv 
with open("file.csv") as file:
    # generator 
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
         # this will print each row as a list/array
         print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for this.  For Example

```py
# importing the module
import pandas as pd
  
# creating a DataFrame
data = {'Name' : ['Sana', 'Manaan', 'Rizwan', 
                 'Uman', 'Usama'],  
        'Computer' : [8, 5, 6, 9, 7],  
        'Farsi' : [7, 9, 5, 4, 7], 
        'Urdu' : [7, 4, 7, 6, 8]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Original DataFrame")
display(df)
  
print("Value of row 3 (Uman)")
display(df.iloc[3]) # Getting the row using iloc

array = []

for i in df.iloc[3]:
  array.append(i)

display(array)
```

first you can read the data from csv. In the above example I just created a simple DataFrame. After that use iloc method to select the specific row. and then just append it in the array. Remember that index starts from 0 so 3 here indicates the 4th row.
Output:

[image: Output]